# How do I use or in PHP?

Tags: php

```
$key = $_REQUEST[ 'key' ] or $key = false;
```

In PHP, what will I get for the $key? What if the script doesn't receive the parameter (key), will it give an error?

In general, how can I use the or in PHP?

This code comes from someone else, and I'm modefying it, because it throws a 500 error if no parameter received. In general, I use the solution that @DaOgre suggested. But I'm more interested in the error, and what will be the correct way to use or in PHP.

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation at all?? http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php

Comment: Do you have experience with languages like JavaScript or Ruby which have conjunctive operators like `var = maybefalse || 'default'`?  PHP doesn't currently have anything as tidy as that, but it is proposed for PHP 7.

Comment: And yes, if `$_REQUEST['key']` is not present, PHP will emit `E_NOTICE undefined index 'key'` Typically that has to be handled with `isset()`  as in `$key = isset($_REQUEST['key']) ? $_REQUEST['key'] : false;` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski The fact is that if I don't send the parameter (key), it gives me a 500 error. I assume the 500 error is the E_NOTICE.

Comment: @Connor E_NOTICE shouldn't generate a 500, which is typically a fatal error (parse or runtime). But in PHP, a 500 always means _go look in your error log_. The error will be detailed out there. And always when developing and testing code, turn on PHP's error display and turn up error reporting. You'll then catch all notices and warnings early. At the top of your script `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` or enable them similarly in php.ini on your development machine.

Comment: @Connor It's possible, I suppose, that there's a custom error handler  in use, which escalates E_NOTICE to something fatal. That would sure be weird though. Here's how it would normally work, and how I would expect yours to behave: http://codepad.viper-7.com/lTAY5m (`$key` should be set false)  In any case, your error log will tell you more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment by Michael Berkowski above the right way to achieve the functionality you're looking for is probably by using a ternary operator

```
<snip>
$key = isset($_REQUEST['key']) ? $_REQUEST['key'] : false;
<snip>
```

This checks to see if the key is set, and if so, returns the first value ($_REQUEST['key']) and if not it returns fase.

You can now perform whatever other logical checks you want to on `$key`.  Keep in mind that you should really sanitize any incoming data that you grab from a from with $_REQUEST.

Comment: I agree with this, and I did the same thing you recommend here. Actually, I'm modifying someone's code, and I saw this. I'm just curious what this code actually does, and I guess PHP will give an error if no parameter received.

Answer (score 0):

This construct takes advantage of the fact that `or` operator is short-circuit, meaning the right-hand part only gets evaluated if the left-hand part evaluates to `true`. Therefore, it is equivalent to:

```
if($_REQUEST['key']) {
    $key = $_REQUEST['key'];
} else {
    $key = false;
}
```

or, using the ternary operator:

```
$key = $_REQUEST['key'] ? $_REQUEST['key'] : false;
```

What that means is `$key` will be set to `false` if `$_REQUEST['key']` is not set *or* it evaluates to `false`, and the value of `$_REQUEST['key']` otherwise.

Note however, that in PHP there's a bunch of things that evaluate to `false`, including: `false` itself, `null`, integer `0`, float `0.0`, empty string, string `'0'`, array with zero elements and a couple of other things, so if you're trying to check whether or not `$_REQUEST['key']` is set, use `isset()` or, better yet, `array_key_exists()` function instead.

Answer (score -3):

it's not or in php but this || try:

```
 $key = $_REQUEST[ 'key' ] || $key = false;
```

Comment: PHP has both `||` and `or` operators which are functionally similar, but with different precedence. http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski in SQL query i know you can use or but also in this procedural script ?, documentation approves it it's a logical operator

Comment: Yes, `or` is a real operator in PHP, similar to but not exactly a substitute for `||`. It is listed in the link above.